# command line tool that will return sound volume ubuntu 12.04

Tags: sound, pavucontrol

Is there a command line tool that will return the output volume setting on pavucontrol.   I can *set* this volume using a python script from some other posting, but cannot figure out how to see what the current setting is.

Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully this will get you started (note the professional way would be hooking into the api http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/Developer/):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output("pacmd list-sinks".split())
on_active_sink = False
i_want_as_db = False
for index, line in enumerate(output.splitlines()):
  line = line.split()
  if ['*', 'index:'] == line[:2]:
    on_active_sink = True
    continue
  if on_active_sink and 'volume:' == line[0]:
    if not i_want_as_db:
      print line[2]
      break
    else:
      print output.splitlines()[index + 1].split()[1]
      break
```

Comment: The output of the above script is in some units that I don't recognize.  To get the sound volume as a percentage I now have the following `bash` command `echo $(expr \`chkSoundVolume\` / 65536 \* 100)%`, where `chkSoundVolume` is the name I assigned to Joe's script.